# PHP DOM how get all image links

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to download pictures from the site for exercises. But something does not work for me, I do not want to display links. Can anyone help me what am I doing wrong ??

This is my code ;)

```php
$li = 'https://gratka.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkanie-katowice-dabrowka-mala/ob/20357919';
                $options3  = array('http' => array('method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Accept-language: pl\r\n" .
                "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n", 
                'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'));
                $context3  = stream_context_create($options3);
                $text1 = file_get_contents($li, false, $context3);

                
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $dom->loadHTML($text1);


$query_string = '';
                 
                  
                 $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
                 foreach ($divs as $div){
                      if(preg_match('/\bgallery__imageViewer\b/', $div->getAttribute('class'))) {
                          $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('img');
                          foreach($links as $link){
                               $foto = $link->getAttribute('src');
                                
                               $query_string .= ('<center><img src="'.$foto.'"> </center><br/>');
                          }
                      }
                 }
print_r($query_string);
```

Thanks in advance to everyone for your help.

Comment: the problem is the gallery is loaded dynamically. your scraping won't be able to get the images from DOM on initial load

Comment: Is there any other way to download the image ?? Eg with python or some other tool in php ??